# os.setuid not working properly

Tags: python, linux, permissions, user-permissions

I have a user on an Ubunutu machine named `user1` that needs to be set to run a script called `myScript.py` from inside the code.

When I set this user,

```
# At the top of myScript.py
uid = pwd.getpwnam('user1')[2]
os.setuid(uid)
```

I get complaints about permissions:

```
Failed to open configuration file: Permission denied
```

Normally I would think the user doesn't have permissions but when I run the following, the user runs the script fine:

```
su user1
user1> python myScript.py
```

Why does the user have permissions when running `su` and not when being set inside the code? Does something else need to be set?

EDIT:
This is quite a bit of code but I'll try and show you what myScript.py is doing

```
uid = pwd.getpwnam('pirate_capture_2')[2]
os.setuid(uid)

# running ffmpeg command with pulse audio
cmd = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -f pulse -ac 2 -i "default" -f x11grab -s "1024x768" -i "{0}" -r 30 -c:v libx264 -crf 10 -preset ultrafast -threads 3 /opt/steamy_rat/frames/{1}.mkv'.format(
        x_display_name, str(job.get('id')))

# runs a subprocess using cmd
```

error occurs

```
W: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to open configuration file '/root/.config/pulse//daemon.conf': Permission denied
```

Although when I am running this script with su user1, I do not get this error and everythign works fine.

Comment: Nothing in your question is trying to open a file.  Can you update the question with a reproducible example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It is quite a bit of code, that is why I was trying to summarize. Ill post some code.

Comment: @ApathyBear Please provide a minimum example.

Comment: You don't need to post all the code; just enough to demonstrate the problem.  Ideally that will be just a few linues.

Comment: I have updated the question with minimal code.

Comment: As far as I know only **root** can do a `setuid`, so if you tried with `sudo` it should work. Now it works with `su` command out of the script cause with this command you explicitly define in the terminal that you indeed are the other user....

Comment: How would I do it in the code with sudo? these are python os operations. And I believe I AM the root user when i set those.

Comment: did you try to run the script with `sudo`  like `sudo python script.py`? To verify that you are root in your script you can make a check like: `if os.getuid() != 0: print "you are not root..."` Also not all os operation require root access ...

Comment: Yes, in fact I change the user id successfully with my python os operation, yet it still doesn't run similarly to how I run it with us from command

Comment: what do you mean "it still doesn't run similarly" ? If you want to resolve this issue it would be better to re-edit your post describing precisely what is the problem, I mean what do you expect from the script and what it outputs instead.